# Insert data into custom table from fetching $_POST values

Tags: array

I get this type of data using `print_r()`

```
  Array ( [0] => test [1] => raviradadiya.ommune-buyer@gmail.com [2] => 1.00 [3] =>    21:16:36 Jun 04, 2015 PDT [4] => 9DS7592P74GMN )
```

Now I want to add this data in my custom table but I cant.

Here is my code

```
  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
    $player_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
    $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
    $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];

    $paypal_str = array($player_name, $payer_email, $payment_gross, $payment_date, $payer_id);
 print_r($paypal_str);

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
    'paypal',
     array(
        'name' =>  $paypal_str[0],
        'email' => $paypal_str[1],
        'amount' => $paypal_str[2],
        'player_id' => $paypal_str[3],
        'date' => $paypal_str[4],
    )
);
}
```

Comment: If the `insert()` does nothing, then add `$wpdb->print_error();` line after it and see what it prints ...

Comment: Don't shout please

Comment: Not working i am tired of check again and again

Comment: Whats your custom table name?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST))
  {
    $player_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
    $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
    $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];

    $paypal_str = array($player_name, $payer_email, $payment_gross, $payment_date, $payer_id);
 print_r($paypal_str);

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
    'paypal',
     array(
        'name' =>  $paypal_str[0],
        'email' => $paypal_str[1],
        'amount' => $paypal_str[2],
        'player_id' => $paypal_str[3],
        'date' => $paypal_str[4]
    )
);
}
```

Remove the unwanted comma from the array.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer but it's not working mat...

Comment: what the error you got ? try $wpdb->last_error after insertion and check the error.  Make sure table name same with that you given.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys it's working properly.

```
 if(!empty($_POST)){

 global $wpdb;
 $player_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
 $payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
 $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
 $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];

 $wpdb->insert( 
'wp_paypal', 
array( 
    'name' => $player_name, 
    'player_id' =>$payer_id,
    'email' =>  $payer_email,
    'amount' => $payment_gross,
    'payment_date' => $payment_date
), 
array( 
    '%s', 
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
) 
);

 }
```

Comment: Please don't **shout**